# Using solve instead of vpasolve to speed up calculations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numeric

I am relatively new to Matlab. At the moment I am solving an equation using vpasolve. Since that needs to loop over 80 variables, it is slow.

```
% input variables
% ffsample = Fourier transformed reference waveform
% ffref = Fourier transformed reference waveform

len=80;
n1=1;
n2=1.95;
alpha_grad=30;
beta_grad=14.858;

% constants
tp12=2.*n1.*cos(alpha)./(n2.*cos(alpha)+n1.*cos(beta));
tp21=2.*n2.*cos(beta)./(n1.*cos(beta)+n2.*cos(alpha));

%functions with unknown n3
syms n3
gamma= asin(n2.*sin(beta)./n3);
rp23 = (n3 .* cos(beta) - n2.*cos(gamma)) ./ (n3 .* cos(beta) + n2 .* cos(gamma));

t = cputime;
res_para=zeros(len,1);

%loop to solve for n3
digits(5):
for i=1:len
    res_para(i)=vpasolve(ffsample(i)./ffref(i) == (tp12*tp21*rp23) ./ (tp12*tp21), n3);
end

e = cputime-t

%convert results to complex numbers
res_para=double(res_para);
res_para=squeeze(res_para);
res_para=res_para';
```

Now, I am trying to convert this into an equation which uses solve before entering the loop. As far as I understand it, I should use solve in conjunction with vpa? At the moment I am trying like the following code, but it wouldn't start:

```
res_p=solve(x == (tp12*tp21*rp23) ./ (tp12*tp21), n3);

t = cputime;
res_para=zeros(len,1);

for i=1:len

    x=ffsample(i)./ffref(i);
    res_para=vpa(res_p(x));
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update

Thank you for your replies. I changed the digits(5) position. 
And yes, digits(5) is a very low value indeed however, it speeds teh above code up by approximately 3 times.

As I said, I am relatively new to matlab and thought that solving the equation symbolically first and then just insert the variables would greatly reduce the time, but maybe I am wrong here.

Considering I use vpasolve to solve a very simple equation numerically:

```
function [ xval ] = example(  )
syms x
for y=1:10
    xval(y) = vpasolve(y == 5.*x+6, x);
end
```

Wouldn't it be faster if I solve the function y=5x+6 symbolically for x first and then just include the msising values in the loop? Something like this:

```
function [ xval ] = example2(  )
syms x
% symbolic solve for x (???)
% y=5x+6 ==> x=(y-6)/5
sol=solve( y == 5.*x+6, x)

for y=1:10
    xval(y) = sol(y);
end
```

Obviously example2 does not work.

Comment: "it wouldnt start" -> have you tried pressing start? Or is there any other problem than "it wouldnt start?

Comment: The error is: "Error using sym>checkindex (line 1545)
Index must be a positive integer or logical.". From what I figurd out, is that vpa excpects one of the symbolic function evaluated. But what i actaually want is to solve the equation for n3 from "solve" for a given x.

Comment: Debug your code and check the value of `x` in`res_para=vpa(res_p(x));`. The most likely thing to happen is that `x` is not an positive integer.

Comment: Is there a reason for using variable precison/symbolics? If your goal is speed, don't use symbolic math at all, but do this numerically. Why do think that `solve` will be faster? Please fix the errors in your code to make it runnable. And you don't need to set `digits` in each `for` loop iteration (5 is a *very* low value). You do need to set it back to it's default when you are done though.